# WCF: Changing Error Messages Language on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

How to change the Spanish to English language in windows 8.1[image]

Comment: can you send the accept-language header?

Comment: @haim770 thank you for the modification

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Your web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```